# Remote report: webexception the operation has timed out

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

I have a ReportViewer which loads a **remote** report fine on the test SharePoint server. I just tried to move it to the production (SharePoint) server, but i get a timeout there when i try to view the report.

The ReportViewer does load up fine on the production server. I also see the default "Loading" message that a ReportViewer always shows and all the input parameters of the report. But after some time (i think a minute or so) i get the error **webexception the operation has timed out** in the place where the report data normally appears.

I have no idea what the problem is. I tried to increase the report timeout, but that didn't seem to have any effect:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Timeout = 1800000;
```

I also copied the web.config of the Test server to the Production server. So there is no difference in there.

Is there anything else i can try...?

Comment: Do you have a `ReportViewerServerConnection` section in your web.config?  Is the timeout set to something different in there?

Comment: @jadarnel27 No, unfortunately there's is not :(